# very fast upstream followed by very slow downstream and out of memory issues

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, slick

I've been taking my experiences gathered from fiddling with akka streams to a practical level and I'm in trouble.
Below is my attempt at writing a streaming pipeline that reads specific rows form a very large database table then **for each row** sends a http call to an external web service than inserts the received responses to another table:

(database library is `slick` and the http client is play framework's )

```scala
val query = (catalogIndices joinLeft catalogSummeries on ((i, s) => i.productId === s.icecatId) filter (t => t._2.isEmpty) map (_._1)).result
val source = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(query))
source
  .buffer(5, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .mapAsync(5) { i =>
    icecatService.fetchCatalog(i.productId, Languages.en, IcecatService.Contents.all)
  }
  .map { r =>
    for {
      g <- (r.json \ "data" \ "GeneralInfo").validate[GeneralInfo]
      img <- (r.json \ "data" \ "Image").validate[Image]
    } yield (g, img)
  }
  .collect {
    case JsSuccess((g, img), _) => CatalogSummeryData(g.IcecatId, g.Title, g.Brand, g.ProductName, g.BrandPartCode,
      g.GTIN, g.Category.CategoryID, g.Category.Name.Value, img.LowPic, img.ThumbPic)
  }
  .grouped(100)
  .runForeach(s => db.run(catalogSummeries ++= s))
```

I can tell that the db as the upstream is very fast and those web service calls are really slow. also if I increase the number of parallelism of the `mapAsync` method much further all my futures timeout.
My problem started when I migrated the entire platform of the project from a Vagrant virtual machine to my windows 10. Now every thing in my code runs much much faster but this piece of streaming is always resulting in GC errors or out of memory errors and such. Back in the virtual machine I once left this code running and successfully streamed 4000 results. how should I tweak this code to get it to perform ?

**Edit**: Also I must mention that on my windows machine absolutely no rows are inserted back before it all shuts down in failure.

**EDIT**: I receive many types of errors but here's a common one:

```
[ERROR] [SECURITY][09/27/2017 07:23:33.046] [application-scheduler-1] 
[akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(application)] Uncaught error from thread 
[application-scheduler-1]: GC overhead limit exceeded, shutting down 
ActorSystem[application]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at akka.dispatch.AbstractNodeQueue.<init>(AbstractNodeQueue.java:32)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskQueue.<init (LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:304)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:269)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but your insert step is running async without any back-pressure to the flow. You might try changing the last insert step from `.runForeach` into `.mapAsync(x)(s => db.run(...)).runWith(Sink.ignore())` and see.

Comment: @PH88 I did as u say and now instead of GC errors and system shutting down, this message appears on the play console every once in a while: `[warn] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - db - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=2m32s834ms149╡s739ns)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `slick` but from the error msg the db insert step would be my first suspect.  You can isolate and confirm by inserting some fake data and see (i.e. Source.tick(x, y, someFakeJson).map(r => ...).collect(...).grouped(100).mapAsync(x)(s => db.run(/* insert*/)).runWith(Sink.ignore())` and see.  Also as the system complains about thread starvation, you might try to set the parallelism of the insert step to 1 (i.e. mapAsync(1)(s=> db.run(...))) and see.

Comment: @PH88 setting parallelism to one worked.